# Interview task, stuck on local database connection, need alternative

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm required to create a bit of software for a company, to illustrate my code use. I'm using .NET CORE Web App MVC and I believe it requires me to use a database but I would need to upload my code on GitHub for them to inspect and run but obviously wouldn't read the database from my machine. What are the alternatives? Can a fake DB be created within the project for instance? Or is there something else I could do that doesn't involve Azure?

I tried scaffolding a DBContext from a controller but it requires a connection of a database

Comment: use file  based databeses like sqllite, csv xml json

Comment: Thanks! I'll be sure to check this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered mocking your data connection? It is the same thing you would do if you were unit testing your application.  You would not want to connect directly to your database; instead, you would create a mock connection and return the data yourself.

You have multiple choices here. You can use a Mock framework like Moq, FakeItEasy, JustMock, and NSubstitute. Otherwise, you can roll your own.

Comment: Thanks I'll be sure to check this out!